# Rails 4 Flot Uncaught Type Error & Error Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, flot

I have a Rails 4 application that uses **flot** to generate charts. Currently, I have one chart that's displaying on a dashboard properly, but when I add a second chart to a different page, it fails to render. And, on both pages, I am getting the following error looking at the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

Here's the CoffeeScript that's calling the two **flot** functions (same file):

```
d1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
$.plot "#flotchart", [d1]

d2 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
$.plot "#flotchart2", [d2]
```

And, in the two separate files, I just have the empty divs:

```
<div id="flotchart"></div>

<div id="flotchart2"></div>
```

Again, the first one shows up just fine, but the second one doesn't show up at all and both have the uncaught type error seen above.

I'm guessing that the type error is due to the **#flotchart** being absent from some pages where the jQuery is still being called (as Rails loads all of them to every page in the development environment)? If so, is there any way to solve this? And then, why isn't the second chart showing up at all?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In what code is the error occurring?  Do you get a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a conflict with a separate JS library that I was loading on the same page. So, my solution was to eliminate the other Javascript that was included but not needed on that page. In Rails, I did that by writing a helper that only included the JS needed.